# Question for friend

Tags: tense

Which one is grammatically sound?

> The vote on the bill will be taking place on Thursday and most people think it **is** an easy government win.

OR

> The vote on the bill will be taking place on Thursday and most people think it **will be** an easy government win.

A similar answer on this forum suggested that 'will be' is better, but 'is' sounds better.

Comment: Both are possible. You might think the future tense version is preferred, but it is idiomatic to use the present tense sometimes like this, as if you are “calling it now” even though it’s a vote in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much, but my friend needs to choose one for an online assignment. Would you happen to know which answer a Japanese instructor might expect?

Comment: For Reference, this is the entire paragraph: "The government [will announce] new tax measures next week. The discussion in Congress [will have been going on] for three months by the time the decision is made, but everyone feels that amount of time was needed to get the decision right. "We['ll read] the details of the tax bill this time next week," said Congresswoman Hillary Turner. "It [will feel] really good as we've been working so long on it."

Comment: cont.    "...The vote on the bill [will be taking place] on Thursday and most people think it [will be] an easy government win. "When we pass this bill, we [will have solved] a major problem with the tax system," says Turner, "and business in this country [will have] a much brighter future." We [will be reporting] the vote live on our website on Thursday and we [will have] a full analysis of the results in the Friday edition of the online newspaper."